# What is the difference between these two sentences.?

Tags: meaning

> He flung the Midgard-Serpent into the seas where it stayed growing ever bigger, and it was only the wolf, Fenris, that he kept in Asgard – because **if the truth be known**, he did not dare take him on directly.

> 1-) because **if the truth be known** 
> 2-) because **if the truth is known**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase [truth be known](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/truth+be+known) is an idiom that is:

> used to tell somebody the true facts about a situation, especially when these are not known by other people.

So your sentence could be rewritten as:

> - because *to tell you the truth*, he did not dare take him on directly.

---

On the other hand, if the *truth is known* is not an idiom, and literally means what it says. An example of this usage would be:

> Don't tell anyone what happened last summer, because if the truth is known, we're all going to get into serious trouble.

---

To emphasize the difference, here's a sentence using both phrases:

> If the *truth is known*, we're going to be arrested, and if the *truth be known*, I'm scared of going to jail.

Which can be rewritten as:

> If *people find out*, we're going to be arrested, and *in all honesty*, I'm scared of going to jail.

As you can see, the meanings of the two phrases are quite different.